# Collapsible footer menu with centered button

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a collapsible bottom menu in JQuery Mobile 1.3. I simply want an horizontal footer at the bottom with an upward pointing arrow. When the footer is clicked, the menu expands and the arrow points downward. This is almost what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/6F2XU/

But I can't seem to be able to center the button at all.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-inset="false"   data-type="horizontal"  data-iconpos="notext" data-position="fixed" class="foot">
<div data-role="collapsible"data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-inset="false"  data-collapsed-icon="arrow-u"  data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" class="center-button" >
<h3>Pets</h3>
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="#">Canary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gerbil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Iguana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mouse</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
.foot{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.ui-btn { width: 100%; height:30px;}
.center-button{
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Here's a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HHnzH/

```
#custom-collapsible h3 a span span.ui-icon {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    margin-top: 2px !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

HTML change, from this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible"data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-inset="false"  data-collapsed-icon="arrow-u"  data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" class="center-button">
```

to:

```
<div data-role="collapsible"data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-inset="false"  data-collapsed-icon="arrow-u"  data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" class="center-button" id="custom-collapsible">
```

I hope this is what you want.

## More info

If you want to learn how to do this kind of changes by yourself you should check this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**, it will teach you how to do this by yourself.

Comment: Yep, this works well. Thank you. Would you know any way to make the button take the entire space of the footer (remove the space between the button and the footer div)?

Comment: Give me a sec to take a look

Comment: You're a pro! Thanks, this works well too. For the original question, I just realized that setting the .ui-btn css changes every button in the App. Any way to customize the button of the collapsible div only?

Comment: Take a look at an example again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .center-button:

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't do anything.